# How to retrieve value of dynamically added entry control value?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I added controls dynamically and want to retrieve entry control values.
Having an issue with retrieving the value.

[image]

My Code:

```
 public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RoundedEntry entry = (RoundedEntry)sender;

        Grid grid = (Grid)entry.Parent;

        RoundedEntry value0 = (RoundedEntry)grid.Children[2];

        string entry0 = value0.Text;

        Debug.WriteLine(entry0);

    }
```

Following this code getting only one entry control value. How I should get other value and store it.

Comment: you should really maintain a reference to each control when you create it

Comment: how should I create a reference in code behind while creating? @Jason

Comment: just store them in a List or Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Loop through all the controls that are RoundedEntry within the Grid and save their value, something like:

```
var entries = new List<string>();
foreach (var child in ((sender as RoundedEntry).Parent as Grid).Children)
{
    if (child is RoundedEntry)
    {
        entries.Add((child as RoundedEntry).Text);
    }
}
```